# How to set resolution to below 360p for youtube in safari browser on ios 15

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, youtube

To avoid unnecessary ads in youtube app i use youtube in safari browser which i installed with some ad blocker add ons.But lowest resolution possible in youtube safari is 360p,but i want to set this to 144p so that i can save my data(I mostly listen to music on youtube). So any idea on how i can set lower resolution in youtube safari ? (I know if i get youtube premium it will solve my problem but i don’t want to take YouTube subscription)

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing YouTube through Safari browser, no - you can only choose the resolution YouTube shows you, and if it doesn't show anything less than 360p you are stuck with that. But there are some YouTube apps that allow you to always play videos at a set resolution. But they will have ads. (One way to partially block all ads on any app is to use DNS ad filtering, like AdGuard DNS, but it is also a privacy risk).

Comment: How is dns blocking a security risk? And YouTube ads are extremely hard to block with dns filtering alone, because the ads of the ads are numerous and change frequently.

Comment: Not per se a security risk but more of a *privacy* risk - any DNS server you use will automatically know all the websites / internet services you use. This is valuable data for advertisers / data brokers.

Comment: Oh yeah, I can see why that would be an issue from the AdGuard point of view. I was thinking of pi-hole, which increases privacy from ISP by using DNS over HTTPS and using cloudflare (privacy-focused).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to avoid ads and also use YouTube mostly to listen to music/audio, you may consider getting a [YouTube Premium](https://www.youtube.com/premium) subscription.

YouTube Premium lets you browse completely ad free, and lets you playback any video using the native mobile apps in the background mode even with the device screen locked in sleep mode.

When you turn off the device screen, YouTube app automatically and seamlessly transitions to only playing back audio, thereby also keeping your mobile data usage low compared to when playing back video. A good side effect would be that you'd be able to get more playback time due to reduced battery consumption.